# Using a $resource parameter for ng-src in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I am using a generic template and fetching JSON data to be displayed in it depending on the value of the URL parameter.

**Service**

```
angular.
module('coreModule.art').
factory('Art', ['$resource', 
    function ($resource) {
        return $resource('json/:artPage.json', {}, {
            query: {
                method: 'GET',
                isArray: true
            }
        });
    }
]);
```

**Routing**

```
$routeProvider.
            when('/:artPage', {
                template: '<art-page></art-page>'
            })
```

**Component**

```
angular.module('artPage').
    component('artPage', {
        templateUrl: 'app/artTemplate.html',
        controller: ['$routeParams', 'Art', 
            function ArtController ($routeParams, Art) {
                this.artWorks = Art.query({artPage: $routeParams.artPage});
            }
        ]
    });
```

**Template**

```
<div ng-repeat="artWork in $ctrl.artWorks">

  <img ng-src="img/doodles_thumbnails/{{artWork.source}}.jpg">      

</div>
```

The URL is '/doodles' in this case and hence 'doodles' is the value of the 'artPage' parameter in the service. Currently, the ng-src attribute is loading images from the 'doodles_thumnbails' folder. I would like to make this value in the ng-src attribute generic.

**So, for another view, if I am loading images for a URL '/paintings', it would be from a folder named 'paintings_thumbnails'. To achieve this, what should I change the ng-src attribute to?**

I am using Angular v1.6.1. I am new to Angular, so please bear with any ignorance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
component('artPage', {
    templateUrl: 'app/artTemplate.html',
    controller: ['$routeParams', 'Art', 
        function ArtController ($routeParams, Art) {
            this.artType = $routeParams.artPage
            this.artWorks = Art.query({artPage: this.artType});
        }
    ]
});
```

then in markup:

```
<div ng-repeat="artWork in $ctrl.artWorks">

  <img ng-src="img/{{artType}}_thumbnails/{{artWork.source}}.jpg">      

</div>
```